# Undefined reference for math.h and angle functions

Tags: c, header, trigonometry

I get an undefined reference messege when I include math.h and angle dependents. (cos, sin...)

Comment: You need to link with the math library, `gcc foo.c -lm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link against math libary.

With `gcc` it is done by adding `-lm` at the end of the line.